# Load testing for less users using Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I have a scenario where there are 3 different types of user logins e.g. Customer users, Counterparty users, Corporate users for an application. Their access changes based on the type of users. But there are only 2000 Counterparty users and 61 Corporate users in production right now. Do I need to create load testing for Counterparty and Corporate users in that case?

There are 3000000 customer users and as per my understanding, load testing is required for customer users definitely.

Customer users have very limited access but they are important as they are customer foccussed. I have created scripts for all the users at the moment but creating data for different types of functionalities is an issue as we cannot reuse data in this case. So i am thinking if just focussing on Customer users will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should simulate the real-life usage of your application as close as possible so you should come up with 3 [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which represent Customers, Counterparties and Corporate users with the appropriate distributions.

The common steps can be put into [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and referenced by the [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller), this way you will [avoid code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)